# $z^i$ and sequences leading up to it

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $D= \mathbb{D} \setminus (-1,0]$, and $f(z) = z^i$. How do you make $f(z)$ a single-valued function on $D$? Is it possible to construct a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_n (z) = z^i$ for all $z \in D $?

I'm not sure how to go about making $f$ a single-valued function. Should I use branch cuts? Regarding the second part of the question, my guess would be no. Can someone ensure me that I'm not wrong here?

Comment: Are you using the dot in $(-1.0]$ as if it were a comma, so it means half-open interval from $-1$ to $0$ ? And $\mathbb{D}$ to denote the closed unit disc in the complex plane?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, it was supposed to be a comma. I have fixed the error. $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the closed unit disc.

Comment: Are we to assume the exponent on $z$ is a posiive integer? If so $z^i$ is aready single valued on the complexes.

Comment: @coffeemath, No it denotes the imaginary unit number $i$, such that $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Look up Runge's Theorem...